# Why is my Ref in React Native not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-ref

I am using React Native to build a Chat messages page.

I have the following code:

```html
import React from 'react';
import {View,ScrollView,Text} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'native-base';

export default class MatchContact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.scrollRef = React.createRef();
}

state = {
  messages: ['message1','message2','message3','message4']
}

handleScroll(){
  this.scrollRef.scrollToEnd()
}

render(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Button onPress={()=>this.handleScroll()}>
        <Text> Scroll To Bottom </Text>
      </Button>
      <ScrollView ref={this.scrollRef}>
         {this.state.messages.map(message => (
             <Text> {message} <Text/>
          ))}
      </ScrollView>
     </View>
  )
}
```

So, when I press the Button 'Scroll to bottom' I expect the ScrollView to scroll to the end of page but i got the error:

**TypeError: _this5.scrollRef.scrollToEnd is not a function. (In '_this5.scrollRef.scrollToEnd()', '_this5.scrollRef.scrollToEnd' is undefined)**

Comment: Try to use `this.scrollRef.current.scrollToEnd()` instead of `this.scrollRef.scrollToEnd()`

Comment: I've answered your question below. I would appreciate an upvote and marking my answer as accepted answer or any other feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to get ref as below

```js
<ScrollView  
keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
ref={(ref) => this.scrollView = ref}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options:

**Option1:**

use `this.scrollRef.current`:

```
handleScroll(){
  this.scrollRef.current.scrollToEnd()
}
```

**or**

**Option2:**

```
<ScrollView ref={ref => this.scrollRef = ref}>
....
</ScrollView>
```